# Unity and Infrared

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, infrared

I would like to make a game where I use a camera with infrared tracking, so that I can track peoples heads (from top view). For example each player will get a helmet so that the camera or infrared sensor can track him/her.

After that I need to know the exact positions of that person in unity, to place a 3D gameobject at the players position.

Maybe there is another workaround to get peoples positions in unity. I know I could use a kinect, but I need to track at least 10 people at the same time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Note: This is not really a closed answer, just a collection of my thoughts regarding your question on how to transfer recorded positions into unity.

If you really need full 3D positions, I believe you won't be happy when using only one sensor. In order to obtain depth information, which can further be used to calculate 3D positions in a reference coordinate system, you would have to use at least 2 sensors.

Another thing you could do is fixing the camera position and assuming, that all persons are moving in the same plane (e.g. fixed y-component), which would allow you to determine 3D positions utilizing the [projection formula](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) given the camera parameters (so camera has to be calibrated).

What also comes to my mind is: You could try to simulate your real camera with a virtual camera in unity. This way you can use the virtual camera to project image coordinates (coming from the real camera) into unity's 3D world. I haven't tried this myself, but there was someone who tried it, you can have a look at that: https://community.unity.com/t5/Editor/How-to-simulate-Unity-Pinhole-Camera-from-its-intrinsic/td-p/1922835

**Edit given your comment:**
Okay, sticking to your soccer example, you could proceed as follows:
*Setup*: Say you define your playing area to be rectangular with its origin in the bottom left corner (think of UVs). You set these points in the real world (and in unitys representation of it) as `(0,0)` (bottom left) and `(width, height)` (top right), choosing whichever measure you like (e.g. meters, as this is unitys default unit). As your camera is stationary, you can assign the corresponding corner points in image coordinates (pixel coordinates) as well. To make things easier, work with normalized coordinates instead of pixels, thus bottom left is `(0,0)` ans top right is `(1,1)`.
*Tracking*: When tracking persons in the image, you can calculate their normalized position (x,y) (with x and y in [0,1]). These normalized positions can be transferred into unitys 3D space (in unity you will have a playable area of the same width and height) by simply calculating a `Vector3` as `(x*widht, 0, y*height)` (in unity x is pointing right, y is pointing up and z is pointing forward).

**Edit on Tracking:**
For top-view tracking in a game, I would say you are on the right track with using some sort of helmet, which enables you to use some sort of *marker based tracking* (in my opinion markerless multi-target tracking is not reliable enough for use in a video game) (if you want learn more about object tracking, there are lots of resources in the field of computer vision).

Independent of the sensor you are using (IR or camera), you would go create some unique marker for each helmet, thus enabling you to identify each helmet (and also the player). A marker in that case is some sort of unique pattern, that can be recognized by an algorithm for each recorded frame. In IR you can arrange quadratic IR markers to form a specific pattern and for normal cameras you can use markers like QR codes (there are also libraries for augmented reality related content, that offer functionality for creating and recognizing markers, e.g. [ArUco](http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26) or [ARToolkit](https://artoolkit.org/), although I don't know if they offer C# libraries, I have only used ArUco with c++ a while ago).

When you have your markers of choice, the tracking procedure is then pretty straightforward, for each recorded image:
- detect all markers in the current image (these correspond to all players currently visible)
- follow the steps from my last edit using the detected positions

I hope that helps, feel free to contact me again.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I wasn't clear enough. I meant I only need 2D positions. Because I want to track people by using a birds eye view. For example they are playing soccer and I am using a camera above them, to track them.

Comment: Thank you again. This really helps me a lot. One last question. I still don't get the "how to track people" part. Do I use infrared or how? Because the pinhole example is not exactly what I am looking for I guess.